# ¿Como obtener las propiedades de una imagen al subirlas en un input file usando JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Lo que espero conseguir es esto:

1. Hago click en un input file.
2. Elijo una imagen
3. Me muestran las propiedades en un div

> Con propiedades me refiero a obtener el nombre de la imagen, tamaño, fecha de creación, formato.

Intente algo como esto:

```js
$('#f1').on('change', function() {
  var dato_archivo = $('#f1').prop("files")[0];
  var fecha = dato_archivo.lastModified;
  alert(fecha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="f1">
```

Pero no me da el resultado esperado, que en este caso seria el obtener la fecha de creación.

> Se acepta tanto EcmaScript como jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La fecha que esta lanzando es correcta, sólo debes formatearla para que sea legible con **[Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date)**

```js
$('#f1').on('change', function() {
  var dato_archivo = $('#f1').prop("files")[0];
  var fecha = new Date(dato_archivo.lastModified);
  alert(fecha);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="f1">
```

Ahora como recomendación te sugiero trabajar con **[momentJS](https://momentjs.com/)** el cual te permite manejar fechas, horas, días, etc además de entregarte infinidad de métodos útiles.

```js
$('#f1').on('change', function() {
  const dato_archivo = $('#f1').prop("files")[0];
  alert(moment(dato_archivo.lastModified).format('DD-MM-YYYY'))
});
```

```html
<input type="file" id="f1">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```